# Frozen Token Account when sending nfts to an address

Tags: nft, spl-token-program, transfer, associated-token-account

I've recently tried to transfer 3 nfts from 3 different collections on 2 different days to a address.

Each time when I've tried transfering them I got 0x11 custom program error. From what I've researched it seems to be frozen token account.

Initally I though it may be some custom logic from the creators but it's kinda odd to be from 3 different collections. Both sender and receiver have paid royalities while usings marketplaces.

Here are the collections:

- Jelly Dawg
- Claynosaurus
- Ooze

sender: ANLMxMkAyHokvUpci9ba9jPiP769gmyNNxQS3gyUGHX9
receiver: CSqhdSh1gErAwGyTCGAhup3ULdKh3qFCSk31K1bvfmJU

Comment: You may have to contact the marketplace directly to see how to transfer these tokens. If they're frozen, there's very little you can do without some interaction with the freeze authority